# Minimize bundle size webpack

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vuetify.js

We are using webpack to bundle our code package. It is observed that when we build with Vue and Vuetify dependency the output file size increased by 1.5+MB.

1. How can we tackle this?
2. Do webpack copy the full code of dependencies in every build?
3. Since vue/vuetify are also used by other apps, can we build separate package for all dependencies and use them directly?